# Using a Razor For loop on an IEnumerable ViewModel - problems accessing by index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am aware that you can't access a value by index when using an `IEnumerable<T>` .

Here is my view:

```
@model IList<CustomerViewModel>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count - 1; i++)
{
     @Model[i].Name
}
```

Notice how I need to make the `ViewModel` of type `IList` in order to use index.

Here is my controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    IList<Customer> customers = _ctx.Reviews.GetCustomers().ToList();

    return View(customers.Select(c => Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel>(c)));
}
```

I am getting an error that is saying that the model item passed into the `ViewDataDictionary` is incorrect.

This makes sense because I guess an IQueryable is going in? Which is why I am trying to keep the `ViewModel` of type `IEnumerable` and still use a for loop.

Comment: `return View(customers.Select(c => Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel>(c)).ToList());`. But you can always use a `foreach` loop in the view if your not creating form controls (or if you are, then use an `EditorTemplate`)

Comment: would a `@foreach` be an option for you? Additionally have a look at the case of your variable (lowercase and uppercase "m")

Comment: @khlr I guess I could use a foreach... My ultimate goal is to be able to add a css class to every other item in the list when looping. I figured I would need to somehow utilize the index to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your model expects the type `IList<CustomerViewModel>`, where in your method `Index` you are passing `IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel>` as model. `IEnumerable<T>` cannot be automatically converted to `IList<T>`, so you get an error.

Easy way to fix the issue is to convert your model to list in `Index` method. You can use LINQ method `ToList()` for that:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    IList<Customer> customers = _ctx.Reviews.GetCustomers().ToList();

    // The result is converted to List using method ToList()
    return View(customers.Select(c => Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel>(c)).ToList());
}
```